# Characterization of an integral operator with a Bessel kernel

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, functional-equations

I am considering the following integral operator: $$K(\sigma)(\theta)=\int_0^{2\pi} \sigma(\theta') J_0(|e^{i\theta}-e^{i\theta'}|)\,d\theta',$$ where $J_0$ is the Bessel function of order $0.$

I am looking for a functional spaces set-up to solve the equation $K(\sigma)(\theta)=f(\theta)$.

My problem comes from the fact that there might be no solution (even in the distributional meaning by interpreting the integral as a duality bracket) for an arbitrary regular function $f$.

Consider for instance $f(\theta)=e^{i\sin(\theta)}=\sum_n J_n(1) e^{in\theta}$. Then, upon writing $J_0(|e^{i\theta}-e^{i\theta'}|)=\sum_n J_n(1)^2 e^{-in\theta'} e^{in\theta}$, one obtains: $$K(\sigma)(\theta)=\sum_n J_n^2(1)\left(\int_0^{2\pi} \sigma(\theta') e^{-in\theta'} \, d\theta'\right) e^{in\theta}. $$ This leads to $\sigma_n=1/J_n(1)$ (denoting $\sigma_n=\int_0^{2\pi} \sigma(\theta')e^{-in\theta'} \, d\theta'$) and thus an exponentially divergent Fourier series for $\sigma$. This does not make sense even in the tempered distributions meaning.

The only thing I can think of is to consider $f$ as a trigonometric polynomial (I do not think that analytic functions would work).

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: $Ks=J*s$ is a convolution operator, so as an operator on $\widehat{s}$, $K$ acts by multiplication by $\widehat{J}$, and since the Fourier coefficients decay, $0$ is in the spectrum of $K$ and there is no bounded inverse $K^{-1}$.

Comment: Dear Christian, thank you for the input, of course you're right, 0 is in the (essential) spectrum of K. Nevertheless, if f as only a finite number of non-null Fourier coefficients then you can find a $\sigma$ satisfying  $K\sigma=f$, the same is true if f has exponentially vanishing Fourier coefficients. So I was trying to find spaces X and Y so that $K: X \to Y$ would be onto. The problem comes from scattering theory and f is in fact the trace on a circle of a solution of Helmholtz equation.